# Creating a CloudSQL instance with a custom instance_type in terraform?

Tags: terraform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to setup a primary master and read replica in cloud sql. when setup manually it looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to create this in terraform now and the documentation mentions [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#instance_type) that they are created on export.

Terraform also gives the following error:

> Can't configure a value for "instance_type": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.

But i cant seem to create them to be that instance type and they always end up as the default `PostgreSQL <version_number>`

How can i set the terraform configs so that I can export them as `ON_PREMISES_INSTANCE` for master and `READ_REPLICA_INSTANCE` for read replica?

Comment: turns out there was another docs here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_source_representation_instance#argument-reference. it seems like you cant create source instance if you are trying for postgres. only mysql seems to be supported

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so that the community can benefit from your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate further from my comment, at the time of writing this, you cannot create any other instance type besides the standard `POSTGRESQL <version>` via terraform.

It seems like you can only create other types for MYSQL with terraform ([see here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_source_representation_instance#argument-reference))

I ended up going with the manual setup involving `gcloud` tool as the deployment of this wont be frequent( docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-replication-from-external#replica.json)). I did come across an answer on using provisioners to solve this. So its worth looking at that option if you are really looking to automate it.